Highlighting text on a page using javascript, where the text is within a link
After clicking a link on a search results page I'm using the following to highlight in yellow (by adding the highlight class), any text on the target page where the value of 'text' is the search term.
This works fine unless the text is within an 'a' tag (link), in particular where the title of the tag contains the search term text.
'
How can I amend so that I also highlight the text within the 'a' tag without breaking it?
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Function to highlight text on the page
    function highlightText(text, content) {
        let highlightedContent = content.replace(new RegExp(text, 'g'), '<span class="highlight">' + text + '</span>');
        document.body.innerHTML = highlightedContent;
    }

    // Function to handle link click
    function linkClickHandler(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let targetPage = this.getAttribute('href');
        fetch(targetPage)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                highlightText('@paramValue', data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching page:', error);
            });
    }

    // Add click event listener to links with class 'lnkTest' when the document is fully loaded
    document.querySelectorAll('.lnkTest').forEach(function (lnkTest) {
        lnkTest.addEventListener('click', linkClickHandler);
    });
});

